# Closing duplicates between StackOverflow and StackExchange

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have found a question on SO, which is very similar to a question on the SE community (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

I have tried to create a flag with the standard flags for it, but it seems that SE community isn't allowed. I am getting the following message:

> The duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow

So I wrote a custom comment to point to the duplicate similar to the following message:

> Possible duplicate of **URL**

This was declined with the comment:

> Please use standard close votes and flags for this.

What is the recommended way to show up duplicates on SE sites?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If only that would have been a question from some other site's meta...

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism for closing a question as a duplicate of a question on another site.

If both relevant posts are on topic for their respective sites, then treat it exactly as if you had found an answer on any site outside of the SE network, namely post an answer, include a link, and summarize enough of the content such that the answer you post answers the question without needing to follow the link, possibly adding whatever additional information you feel is relevant.

If one of the questions are offtopic for their respective sites, perhaps one question should be migrated to the other site.  Note that there is an overlap between some sites, so while this option should be considered, it's certainly possible that nether question requires migration.